# Spring Data Repository - composite key & don't need to save entity

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, entity, projection

I'm working with a third party database that is read-only. I have the following Spring Data repository:

```
public interface FolderRepository extends Repository<Folder, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT f.folderId, a.fileId, a.fileName, " //selecting other columns in my app
            + "FROM User.functionSys(:binData) f " 
            + "LEFT JOIN User.vFile a " 
            + "ON f.fileId = a.fileId " 
            + "group by f.folderId, a.fileId, a.fileName",
           nativeQuery = true)
    List<Folder> getFolders(@Param("binData") byte[] binData);
}
```

Folder id and file id form an unique key. So, my folder entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Folder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private FolderFileKey id;

    private String fileName;

    // several other fields in my app   
}

@Embeddable
@Data
class FolderFileKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    private Integer folderId;
    private Integer fileId;
}
```

The problem is that I really want a list of `File` objects where each `File` object contains a list of `Folder`s (**the same file id may be in several different folders**):

```
@Data
public class FileDto {

   private Integer fileId;
   private String fileName;
   private List<Folder> folders;

}

@Data
public class FolderDto {
   private Integer folderId;
   private String folderName;
}
```

I know that I could write a service to transform a Folder entity into the FileDto and FolderDto but is there a way to use Spring Data projections or rewrite the entities to achieve the structure wanted in the Dtos?

**Update**

`User.functionSys(:binData)` is a table-valued function (so it returns a table).

Comment: What does `User.functionSys(:binData)` return? Is it a temporary table, a cursor from an existing table, ...? If `Folder` maps onto a physical table or view, then your query could read `SELECT ... FROM files f WHERE f.folderId IN (SELECT folderId FROM User.functionSys(:binData))`. Your setup would also become a pretty standard `@ManyToOne` scenario

Comment: @crizzis - Great question. Sorry I forgot to note that. It returns a table (updated the OP). Here's the definition of the function: 'CREATE FUNCTION [User].[functionsys](@binData [varbinary](max)) RETURNS TABLE(--many columns) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS EXTERNAL NAME [SqlCrlUtil]....'
RETURNS  TABLE (

Comment: @crizzis - With your solution, how would I get other columns from the table-valued function, `User.functionSys`, such as folderName?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, `Folder` does **not** map onto a physical table, since the function returns a temporary table. Forget my solution, it does not apply here